# react kubernetes deployment, port 80 only works

Tags: docker, kubernetes, deployment, yaml, containers

I'm learning how kubernetes works, and I've deployed a basic react app (using create-react-app).

In my yaml file I've set **containerPort: 80**, and then used a NodePort service targeting port 80. Everything works fine.

BUT. Why does it only work with port 80? I've tried containerPort 3000, doesn't work. Nor 8080 etc.

**Is there something special about port 80? Why does it only work when I use that port?**

Below is my yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-app
        image: <my repo>/my-app
        ports:
            - containerPort: 80
      restartPolicy: Always
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    name: my-app
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
      nodePort: 30001
```

Comment: The container runs a program; what port is that program listening on?  That should match the pod's `containerPort` and the service's `targetPort`.  There's nothing magical about port 80 beyond being the default HTTP port, but the two ports in the Kubernetes config need to match what the process in the container is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `basic react app (using create-react-app)` is serving on 80 port.

You might check it on `index.js` or `npm start`. (I'm not good at React.js)

And the `containerPort` is for [publishing/exposing port](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose).

So, there's nothing can serve when you try to publish 3000 port but your docker image(container) is serving content on 80 port

Comment: The react app is serving on port 3000. Which is why it's weird that only 80 works

Comment: Can you show your Dockerfile and entrypoint of `image: <my repo>/my-app`?